# Powershell regex only select digits

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a script that I am working on to parse each line in the log. My issue is the regex I use matches from src= until space.

I only want the ip address not the src= part. But I do still need to match from src= up to space but in the result only store digits. Below is what I use but it sucks really badly. So any help would be helpful

```
#example text

$destination=“src=192.168.96.112 dst=192.168.5.22”

$destination -match 'src=[^\s]+'

$result = $matches.Values

#turn it into string since trim doesn’t work

$result=echo $result

$result=$result.trim(“src=”)
```

Comment: Looks like you want `$destination -match '(?<=src=)\S+'`. Do you need to extract all values?

Comment: Thanks just wanted to match after src until space just getting ip part out. This works and will be using it for other fields in the log text.

Comment: Then, use `Select-String '(?<=src=)\S+' -input $destination -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Value}`, or `Select-String '(?<=src=)\S+' -input $destination -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind here, and since `-match` only returns the first match, you will be able to access the matched value using `$matches[0]`:

```
$destination -match '(?<=src=)\S+' | Out-Null
$matches[0]
# => 192.168.96.112
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3Dsrc%3D%29%5CS%2B&i=src%3D192.168.96.112%20dst%3D192.168.5.22).

- `(?<=src=)` - matches a location immediately preceded with `src=`
- `\S+`  - one or more non-whitespace chars.

To extract all these values, use

```
Select-String '(?<=src=)\S+' -input $destination -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Value}
```

or

```
Select-String '(?<=src=)\S+' -input $destination -AllMatches | % {$_.Matches} | % {$_.Value}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using a capturing group:

```
src=(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=src%3d%28%5cS%2b%29&i=src%3d192.168.96.112+dst%3d192.168.5.22) | [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyUltbgkMy@xJDM/z/ZRw5ziomRbQ0sjPUMzCz1LMz1DQyOFlOISuJCpnpHRo4a5XCoFiSUlqUV5CrYK6iAtGjHB2prqXMGpOanJJbrBJUWZeekKcEW6mXkFpSUKyHYp6Drm5PgmliRnpBYr1Ci45RelJiZn6PonZQENUKhWideDStZil3Uvyi8tKI42jNULS8wpTa39/x8A)

For example

```
$destination=“src=192.168.96.112 dst=192.168.5.22”
$pattern = 'src=(\S+)'
Select-String $pattern -input $destination -AllMatches | Foreach-Object {$_.Matches} | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
```

Output

```
192.168.96.112
```

---

Or a bit more specific matching the dot and the digits *(or see this page for an even [more specific match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) for an ip number)*

```
src=(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```